# Using new database for testing or creating mocked data cloud foundry and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I am working on a project that uses AWS and we are putting our data in MySQL database. The project is very long and it mostly deals with database. Our database structure may change every but our data in database keeps changing rather frequently ( like once every 15 days). If data changes this results in failing system integrator tests as we perform it on real database. Hence we came up with two ideas one was to create a mock data and put it in our database and test with it ( most of the time it will work) but it is a tedious task as database is rather complicated. Another was to create a new database and copy current data from it (it will work because right now all test cases pass). This will save our time to create mock data. We will run our test cases in Dev and acceptance in this environment and do a CF bind in production so it is like writing one additional line of binding and unbinding. We are using blue green deployment so downtime is not a problem. 
Can someone suggest which is a better approach?

One seperate database for testing ( I have never seen this)
Or creating mocked data ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database schema is not overly complex, I suggest you use an in-memory db like H2 or HSql db. You can load all necessary data sets as part of the setup, then run the tests for all conditions.

At the end of the tests, the H2 instances will be wiped out. And your actual db is left unaffected.

One caveat, being in-memory db, you will want to rationalize the amount of test data that you put in during setup. So, you can have multiple test suites, each having its own set of test data (subset of the overall).

You can control such behaviors using active profiles.

Comment: we always use in memory database for development purposes because its fast and we can create and destroy tables as per a test case i.e create database schema and records as per your test case requirements and throw it away
Mocking data for external sources is fine e.g you are hitting an API lets say Google Map in your app, you don't have to really call that API in testcase or Lets say you are sending emails in your code, those you can mock

Comment: We also use in memory database with mocked data that we create and destroy during execution of runtime. But this does not solves the problem of testing original data and what if database schema changes?